# FULLTEXT index in Yii 2 migrations

Tags: yii2, database-migration

How to add a `FULLTEXT` index for a field using Yii 2 migrations?

There is no `createFulltextIndex` or `createUniqueIndex` method(s). [Class `yii\db\Migration` docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-migration.html#createIndex()-detail).

How to solve this with Yii 2 migrations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`FULLTEXT` is not supported because it's schema specific.
Still you can use raw SQL for this.

MySQL example:

```
$this->execute("ALTER TABLE table_name ADD FULLTEXT INDEX index_name (column_name ASC)");
```

Comment: Thanks! Very neat!

Answer (score 2):

If  some sql command are not mapped in http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-migration.html class  you can use the normal  createCommand for sql

eg if you want create a table as select you can use

```
$sql =" select * from my_table ";

$command = Yii::$app->
         db->createCommand("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX NOT EXISTS MY_NEW_TABLE AS " . $sql);
$command->execute();
```

so in your case you can  perform an alter table for adding the fulltext index

```
 $command = Yii::$app->
         db->createCommand("ALTER TABLE your_table ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `FullText` (`col1`, `col2` ););"
```